# Perl hash store and retrieve Byte order is not compatible in windows to linux server?

Tags: perl, perl-module

storefile.pl

```
    use Data::Dumper;
    use Storable;
    my %hashsample;
    $hashsample{'id1'}="name1";
    $hashsample{'id2'}="name2";
    $hashsample{'id3'}="name3";
    store(\%hashsample, "Hashfile.txt");
```

retrievefile.pl

```
    use Data::Dumper;
    use Storable;
    my %newhash = %{retrieve("Hashfile.txt")};
```

erorr

```
    Software error:

    Byte order is not compatible at /usr/local/lib/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux/Storable.pm
```

I  Have large file.....

if i store windows only working at windows server not in linux server. 
so i want store from linux server then this method work. 
i need hash store any server and retrieve any server.

any other fast method store and retrieve hash file in perl?

Comment: Does it work if you use `nstore()` instead of `store()`?

Comment: not working"Undefined subroutine &main::nstore called at storefile.pl" not stroing

Comment: Please import the function explictely or write `Storable::nstore()`.

Comment: use Storable qw(nstore); nstore(\%hashsample, "Hashfile.txt"); working

Comment: @SlavenRezic your answer can't be accepted as you didn't wrote one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try nstore() instead of store().

```
use Storable 'nstore';
...
nstore(\%hashsample, "Hashfile.txt");
```